# TypeScript functions on Firebase - paths problem

Tags: typescript, firebase

My Firebase project has TypeScript functions implemented with the following directory hierarchy:

```
- functions
  - src
    - index.ts
  - shared
    - other.ts
  - tsconfig.json
  - package.json
```

My `tsconfig.json` file looks like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

And my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec 'test/**/*.ts'" 
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
     "dep": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I'm able to compile the project with `npm run build` (which translates to `tsc -b`), but can't serve (`firebase emulators:start`) due to the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module './functions/lib/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

To my surprise, the `lib` folder contains two new `src` & `shared` folders instead of the "compiled" JS directly under it. How can I fix it?

Comment: after tsc, check the contents of lib folder

Comment: As I've writted, the content is two directories (`src` & `shared`), with `src` containing `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

in package.json you will need to add the following

```
"main": "lib/src/index.js",
```

This is because of the two folders, as you have mentioned.